# Can you specify timeout on Android AIDL calls?

Tags: android, aidl

I understand that [AIDLs](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/guide/components/aidl.html) provide synchronous IPC mechanism. When a client binds to an AIDL API, the request is synchronized. The client waits for the response. Is is possible to specify a timeout for AIDL calls?

Comment: no, there is no such way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the calls are synchronous by default. However, you can create an AIDL based interface which is asynchronous. Usually this is done with the "client" application implementing a "listener" type AIDL interface (also async):

MyListener.aidl:

```
oneway interface MyListener {
    void callback(int status);
}
```

MyService.aidl:

```
oneway interfave MyService {
    void doSomething(int arg, MyListener listener);
}
```

Note that these are two different files.